# Cell border change affects whole table markup

Tags: html, css, border, cell, css-tables

I have table with next style:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

td, th {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align:center;
}

th {
    border: 0;
}
```

When I change border width of one or few cells, rows' and columns' width, and whole table width changes in undefined way. It's not so serious, byt I want prevent any visual changes at all, except border of affected cells. Changing these cells width or height not helps.
How do I prevent modifying table position and only change border width of needed cells?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tm9k6/)

---

UPD Problem is fixed. I just add two rows and columns at right and bottom of the table, and set border to 2px in last row and column.

Comment: please provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: remember: border:0px not border:0

Comment: Here is [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tm9k6/). JavaScript not works at all, so you can just click any cell in 4th row, or last cell.

Comment: OK, what is the difference between border:0px and border:0?

Comment: @javascriptisfuture: it makes no difference; zero is zero, and the units are optional.

Answer (score 0):

border-collapse:collapse means that all your cells borders get mashed together and therefore take on the same style as well.

[See this link](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-collapse/)

> collapse - in which both the space and the borders between table cells collapse so there is only one border and no space between cells.